# cut command to delimit the output and add them

Tags: linux, bash

I am new in bash
I wrote a bash script and it gives me an output like this:

```
3387 /test/file1
23688 /test/file2
5813 /test/file3
10415 /test/file4
1304 /test/file5
46 /test/file6
8 /test/file7
138 /test/file8
```

I can delimit them by

```
 wc -l /path/to/$dir/test | cut -d" " -f1
```

how can I add numbers to eachother and caculate them?
can I do:

```
output=`wc -l /path/to/$dir/test | cut -d" " -f1`
```

Is it possible to use "while" or "for" loop and add those numbers?
how?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `awk` here to avoid explicit loops.  If your output was in the file `data.txt` you could use:

```
$ awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}' data.txt
44799
```

In your case, pipe the output of your script to `awk`:

```
$ your_script.sh | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'
```

Since the output you gave in your question was the output of `wc -l`, try:

```
$ wc -l /path/to/$dir/test | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'
```

(Aside for anyone else landing on this page: `wc -l`, when given wildcards, will also give you a total, but it's great to use `awk` in this case because you can deal directly with the total line count and pipe just that to another process.)

Comment: I don't want to read from text file.I want to calculate from my output appears in terminal..thank you if you can tell me how